# Python Web-Scraping data that's not hard-coded into the HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to scrape pricing data from insight.com.  Here's an [example page](https://www.insight.com/en_US/buy/product/V1Q00UT%23ABA/HP%20INC/V1Q00UT%23ABA/HP-ZBook-17-G3-Mobile-Workstation--173%22--Core-i7-6700HQ--8-GB-RAM--500-GB-HDD/).

From that page, I'd like to pull the ListPrice.  I've done this before with requests and BeautifulSoup, but on those occasions the price would be directly in the HTML so it was rather easy to pull out.  However, Insight appears to be getting this price data from "webProduct.prices[0].price", which I assume is a javascript object.

Here's the exact HTML element:

```
 <p class="ips-price-contract">List price</p><p class="prod-price">{{- webProduct.prices[0].currency }}&nbsp;{{= numeral(webProduct.prices[0].price).format(InsightUtil.GetCurrencyFormat()) }}</p>
```

Is there a way I can still get this pricing data with Python?

**EDIT: Solution Below**

Thanks to Harun Ergül's solution below, I was able to get this working.  First, I used the app postman to get the post working through there.  Here's what the finished post looks like:
 [image: Post] [image: Json Payload in Body]

To translate the json payload to python, I first formatted it as a python dict (e.g. replacing 'null' with 'None', 'true' and 'false' with 'True' and 'False', etc.) and then made the request with data=json.dumps(data)

Comment: price provided by javascript. But there should be a way. I try to figure out

Comment: As @HarunErgül mentioned If indeed this is a one time script, then doing the requests to the api directly is sufficient and a lot faster. However, selenium is a very useful browser instrumentation framework built on top of the w3c webdriver protocol. If you are interested in this area, I would definitely suggest on learning how to use it.

Comment: I am also using selenium. It is really useful tool. But for large data set it is really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website makes extra request for the price. You should imitiae the same request.You can find it under chrome network xhr tab.

[image]

Don't use selenium kind of solution because it takes time to scrap a large set of data.

Comment: I was actually just looking at this after reviewing the above answer by  Giannis.  

What I'm unsure of is how to replicate this request through the requests package.  I see that it's accessing the url "https://www.insight.com/insightweb/compareProducts", but I'm not sure what else I should be adding onto this.  

Do you have an example or reference to someplace where I can read more to figure out how to replicate this request?

Comment: You see there is Headers tab in the picture. In this part you  will see "request headers".  You should include this header information in your requests.  
 http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: What about some of the header information that's "visit specific" such as the Set-Cookie, and the "ADRUM" headers (someof these include things that look like customer id's)

Comment: Actually this part becomes a difficult most of the times. You have to try. I think requests api handles the cookies.  ADRUM is under response headers. maybe you don't have to use ADRUM  data in your get request.

Comment: I noticed that if I have 'Content-Length' : '614' in the header, I get a 503 response.  If I take that out, it works but this is what's returned:
    {"changes":[],"referer":"https://www.insight.com/en_US/buy/product/V1Q00UT%23ABA/HP%20INC/V1Q00UT%23ABA/HP-ZBook-17-G3-Mobile-Workstation--173%22--Core-i7-6700HQ--8-GB-RAM--500-GB-HDD/","path":"/content/insight-web/en_US/buy/product","location":"/content/insight-web/en_US/buy/product","parentLocation":"/content/insight-web/en_US/buy","status.code":200,"status.message":"OK","title":"Content modified /content/insight-web/en_US/buy/product"}

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't give me the full payload that I see in Chrome's "request Payload" box. Any ideas?

Comment: I think "request Payload"  comes inside response of your first request of page. Later you should add these payload to  "compareProduct" request. Scrapping this kind of website is tiredsome and need analyse of how it works.

Comment: My suggestion is use chrome extension "Postman". You can analyze your requests with postman.

Comment: Thanks again, I got it working after testing everything in postman :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138342/discussion-between-harun-ergul-and-trolliolli).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle javascript enabled pages, is to use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with a browser (there are drivers for all real-world browsers like chrome, firefox etc and even for headless browsers like phantomjs). This stack will fetch your page and run all javascript associated with the page. You can then get the processed source and extract your data from there (since now `{{- webProduct.prices[0].currency }}&nbsp;{{= numeral(webProduct.prices[0].price).format(InsightUtil.GetCurrencyFormat()) }}` would be replaced by the actual price)

```
driver.get(page)
page_source = driver.source
```

Alternatively you can inspect the page in an actual browser, monitor its network activity, find out what api requests the page makes to get the necessary data and replicate those with the requests library.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!